# how to search in Youtube and play Video in Windows Phone

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7

I am beginner in windows phone.

And i have to search in you tube for the video..
and bind that videos in to the list box and when the user clicks on any video.

The video is played in windows phone.

Please suggest me any blog or msdn documentation for this.

Comment: please show your code what you have done upto now.

And always be ready with your code. so, any one suggest you the solution.

Comment: @Nikhil, thanks.

But i have no idea so, how can i show you the code.?
Please suggest me any documentations or the examples.

Comment: ok..
I will show you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this link, you can solve your doubts.

This shows how can you get the youtube videos and how to bind that videos in listbox.
and the selected video is played in windows phone.

**[Youtube Search and play Video in Windows Phone](http://dotnetternikhil.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/youtube-search-and-play-video-in-windows-phone/)**

I hope you get the Answer.